# How to use mongodb _id to find record

Tags: php, mongodb

I am doing project with mongodb and php. so I am trying to find record using it _id. here I post json value like this way

```
{"_id": {"$id": "513ea9d4a00b2ade09000001"}}
```

then I get this value and decode it and use to find like this way

```
$obj = json_decode( $json, true);
$result = $collection->find($obj);
```

but above code give error because in the json their is a key like `$id`. so how I solve above problem please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a JSON string it is slightly different to all the examples shown currently.

Since you now have an object of an assoc array which looks like:

```
array(
    '_id' => array(
        '$id' => "513ea9d4a00b2ade09000001"
    )
)
```

You must extract that `$id` property and cast it to a `MongoId` like so:

```
$db->collection->find(new MongoId($obj['$id']));
```

That will find your record.

Answer (score 4):

Please follow this example:

```
// This is only a string, this is NOT a MongoId
$mongoid = '4cb4ab6d7addf98506010000';

// You will not find anything by searching by string alone
$nothing = $collection->find(array('_id' => $mongoid));
echo $nothing->count(); // This should echo 0

// THIS is how you find something by MongoId
$realmongoid = new MongoId($mongoid);

// Pass the actual instance of the MongoId object to the query
$something = $collection->find(array('_id' => $realmongoid));
echo $something->count(); // This should echo 1
```

You could find more info [here](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/26903435041/mongodb-for-the-php-mind-part-2).

Answer (score 1):

To find document using '_id' you have to typecast it to MongoId Object. This can be done by passing `array('_id' => new MongoId($valOf_id) )` in the find query.

I did not write a verbose answer as I am sure this is enough for you to get the point right :-)